# Animating CSS columns and SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations

I am trying to make an effect in CSS to bring next to each other two columns an svg that would be an illustration of the product and some text like a description. so they "slide-in" I want to do this with many products.
But i am completely stuck.

First: the layout. I cant align the two columns (the svg and the text) vertically and i cant bring them close enough to each other.

Second: the animation. the text disappears after the animation is done but only in the browser, not in the live mode of dreamweaver.

My full code is here: http://pastebin.com/MkA7AQxA

I know this could be considered 2 different questions and should be posted separately, but maybe the problems are correlated.

Thank you very much for your help, since i am very anxious.

```css
#wrapper {
  margin: 2em auto;
  width:800px;
  position:relative;
  padding: 4rem 0;      
}
 
.animBlock {
  margin: 4rem -4rem 0 -2rem;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  column-count: 2;
                               
}
.animBlock li {
  position:relative;
  display: block;    
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 2rem 2rem 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  break-inside: avoid;
   
}
 
.animBlock_left {
  animation-name: come_left;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 
}
 
.animBlock_right {
  animation-name: come_right;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 
}
 
 @keyframes come_left {
        0% {transform: translateX(-200px); opacity:0;} 
        100% {transform: translateX(0);}       
 }
 
 @keyframes come_right {
        0% {transform: translateX(200px); }    
        100% {transform: translateX(0);}       
 }
```

```html
       
 <div id="wrapper" >
   
       
     
        <ul id="bote" data-position="left" class="animBlock">
        <li class="animBlock_left">
         <svg   x="0px" y="0px"
    viewBox="0 0 3000 3000" enable-background="new 0 0 2400 2400" >
         <g>
        <g>
                <path fill="#BCBEC0" d="M153.1,1489.8c0,14,11.4,25.4,25.4,25.4H509c13.9,0,25.4-11.4,25.4-25.4v-406.9H153.1V1489.8z"/>
                <path fill="#D1D3D4" d="M447.8,1125.6c0-7,5.7-12.7,12.7-12.7h20.8c7,0,12.7,5.7,12.7,12.7v345.2c0,7-5.7,12.7-12.7,12.7h-20.8
                        c-7,0-12.7-5.7-12.7-12.7V1125.6z"/>
                <path fill="#D1D3D4" d="M363,1125.6c0-7,5.7-12.7,12.7-12.7h20.8c7,0,12.7,5.7,12.7,12.7v345.2c0,7-5.7,12.7-12.7,12.7h-20.8
                        c-7,0-12.7-5.7-12.7-12.7V1125.6z"/>
                <path fill="#D1D3D4" d="M278.2,1125.6c0-7,5.7-12.7,12.7-12.7h20.8c7,0,12.7,5.7,12.7,12.7v345.2c0,7-5.7,12.7-12.7,12.7h-20.8
                        c-7,0-12.7-5.7-12.7-12.7V1125.6z"/>
                <path fill="#D1D3D4" d="M193.4,1125.6c0-7,5.7-12.7,12.7-12.7h20.8c7,0,12.7,5.7,12.7,12.7v345.2c0,7-5.7,12.7-12.7,12.7h-20.8
                        c-7,0-12.7-5.7-12.7-12.7V1125.6z"/>
        </g>
        <path fill="#A7A9AC" d="M539.4,1019.2h-121v-13.1c0-7-5.7-12.7-12.7-12.7h-124c-7,0-12.7,5.7-12.7,12.7v13.1H148
                c-7,0-12.7,5.7-12.7,12.7v38.3c0,7,5.7,12.7,12.7,12.7h391.4c7,0,12.7-5.7,12.7-12.7v-38.3C552.1,1024.9,546.4,1019.2,539.4,1019.2
                z"/>
</g>
</svg>
        </li>
                           <li id="boteTxt" data-position="right" class="animBlock_right">
          <h3>The New Product</h3>
          <p>some deescription about the product</p>
       </li>
   </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please include some code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem 1: too much space around SVG**

This is because your `viewBox` is absolutely ginormous.  Your garbage can image is roughly 417x522, but your viewBox says it is 3000x3000.  So the first step is to fix that:

```
<svg viewBox="135 994 417 522" ...
```

**Problem 2: animation not working in the browser**

Are you testing in Chrome or Safari by any chance?  CSS animation is still not finalised, so you still need to use the `-webkit-` prefix on your `animation` and `@keyframes` properties.  Note that you need to also have the unprefixed versions for Firefox.

```css
#wrapper {
  margin: 2em auto;
  width: 200px;
  position:relative;
  padding: 4rem 0;      
}
 
.animBlock {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  column-count: 2;
                               
}
.animBlock li {
  position:relative;
  display: block;    
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 2rem 2rem 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  break-inside: avoid;
   
}
 
.animBlock_left {
  -webkit-animation-name: come_left;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

  animation-name: come_left;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
 
.animBlock_right {
  -webkit-animation-name: come_right;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

  animation-name: come_right;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
 

 @-webkit-keyframes come_left {
        0% {transform: translateX(-200px); opacity:0;} 
        100% {transform: translateX(0);}       
 }
 
 @-webkit-keyframes come_right {
        0% {transform: translateX(200px); }    
        100% {transform: translateX(0);}       
 }


 @keyframes come_left {
        0% {transform: translateX(-200px); opacity:0;} 
        100% {transform: translateX(0);}       
 }
 
 @keyframes come_right {
        0% {transform: translateX(200px); }    
        100% {transform: translateX(0);}       
 }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" >
   
       
     
        <ul id="bote" data-position="left" class="animBlock">
        <li class="animBlock_left">
         <svg   x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="135 994 417 522" >
         <g>
        <g>
                <path fill="#BCBEC0" d="M153.1,1489.8c0,14,11.4,25.4,25.4,25.4H509c13.9,0,25.4-11.4,25.4-25.4v-406.9H153.1V1489.8z"/>
                <path fill="#D1D3D4" d="M447.8,1125.6c0-7,5.7-12.7,12.7-12.7h20.8c7,0,12.7,5.7,12.7,12.7v345.2c0,7-5.7,12.7-12.7,12.7h-20.8
                        c-7,0-12.7-5.7-12.7-12.7V1125.6z"/>
                <path fill="#D1D3D4" d="M363,1125.6c0-7,5.7-12.7,12.7-12.7h20.8c7,0,12.7,5.7,12.7,12.7v345.2c0,7-5.7,12.7-12.7,12.7h-20.8
                        c-7,0-12.7-5.7-12.7-12.7V1125.6z"/>
                <path fill="#D1D3D4" d="M278.2,1125.6c0-7,5.7-12.7,12.7-12.7h20.8c7,0,12.7,5.7,12.7,12.7v345.2c0,7-5.7,12.7-12.7,12.7h-20.8
                        c-7,0-12.7-5.7-12.7-12.7V1125.6z"/>
                <path fill="#D1D3D4" d="M193.4,1125.6c0-7,5.7-12.7,12.7-12.7h20.8c7,0,12.7,5.7,12.7,12.7v345.2c0,7-5.7,12.7-12.7,12.7h-20.8
                        c-7,0-12.7-5.7-12.7-12.7V1125.6z"/>
        </g>
        <path fill="#A7A9AC" d="M539.4,1019.2h-121v-13.1c0-7-5.7-12.7-12.7-12.7h-124c-7,0-12.7,5.7-12.7,12.7v13.1H148
                c-7,0-12.7,5.7-12.7,12.7v38.3c0,7,5.7,12.7,12.7,12.7h391.4c7,0,12.7-5.7,12.7-12.7v-38.3C552.1,1024.9,546.4,1019.2,539.4,1019.2
                z"/>
</g>
</svg>
        </li>
                           <li id="boteTxt" data-position="right" class="animBlock_right">
          <h3>The New Product</h3>
          <p>some deescription about the product</p>
       </li>
   </ul>
        </div>
```